# Display error message with jQuery without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, html5

I created login form. When user clicks on login button this form shows up with some fade effect (jQuery). What I want to do is to display error message in this form when user inputs invalid data. Before showing any messages, PHP must read data from database, therefore page must be reloaded and when page is reloaded this form fade away. How can I display error message in this login form without reloading page?

(I have lots of code so if you need any part of code I will provide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is JQuery's ajax methods.

They can get data from the server and update your dom on the fly without a page reload.

This is pretty straightforward using [Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

JQuery also has some other [ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) which may be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my login jQuery/AJAX proccess script.
You just need to create a few divs/spans in your form for error message and loading and to make this work, in your login PHP script you must add if login is correct echo'1'; or whatever is your success echo in your PHP script change that in this part of jQuery code

```
if(result === '1' ) {  // This is PHP success echo, in my case is number 1

  window.location='index.php';  // Uppon successfull login in my case redirects to index.php 
}
```

---

```
$(function() {

  $( '.login' ).submit(function(e) { // My form has class login, dont forget to change this to your form class or id

    e.preventDefault();

    var error   = 0;

    var lForm   = $( this ),
        lName   = $( '.login input[name="login"]' ).val(),
        lPass   = $( '.login input[name="password"]' ).val(),
        errMsg  = $( '.login-err' ); // Create div or span with class login-err or whatever class you wish


    if ( lName == 'Username' ) {  // Username in this case is default value
      error = 1;
      errMsg.html( '<p>Enter User Name and Password.</p>' ); //Here insted .html you could use .text
    }

    if ( lName.length > 32 || lName.length < 3 ) {
      error = 1;
      errMsg.html( '<p>Name must be between 3-32 characters.</p>' );
    }

    if ( lPass == 'Password' ) {  // Password in this case is default value
      error = 1;
      errMsg.html( '<p>Enter User Name and Password.</p>' );
    }

    if ( error ) {                  
      errMsg
        .fadeIn( 'slow' )
        .delay( 1800 )
        .fadeOut( 'slow' );

        return false;
    }
    else {

      $( this ).fadeOut(function() {

        $( '.loading' ).fadeIn(function() { // For this create div or span with class "loading" or whatever class you wish and put some pretty loader gif in it

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: lForm.attr( 'action' ),
            data: lForm.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {

              if(result === '1' ) {
                window.location='index.php';
              }
              else {

                $( '.loading' ).fadeOut(function() {

                  lForm.fadeOut( 'slow' );

                   errMsg
                     .fadeIn( 'slow' )
                     .delay( 1800 )
                     .fadeOut( 'slow' )
                     .html( '<p>Incorrect User Name or Password.</p>' );

                   lForm.delay( 2400 ).fadeIn( 'slow' );

                 });
                }
              }
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I solved my problems. Here is my work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DBGA65Cu04